# If I setup a whitelist for every GET variable in a php webpage, am I safe?

Tags: php, sql, security, post, get

I'm concerned about my site's security. I am developing a site in a very competitive niche and have indeed been hacked before. My site has some pages where GET variables are being sent.

Reading tens of questions leads to the conclusion that nothing really works in the end because even after stripping tags and doing fancy stuff people who really want to be cute can still do harmful stuff.

So I decided to introduce a white list for ALL variables which has ALL the allowed values, and if not send error log and kill the page. Am I good here? Or is that still bad?

My database does not have any crucial info and I stripped the user from most rights to SQL and left only Select, Update etc..

In general I'm a bit lost, is what I did enough? do I need to use any PHP functions to deal with the variables? Do I still need to escape it? Really the more I read the more the website gets delayed because I am worried about security.

Edit: To be more clear, here is what I did:

```
if (isset($_GET['variable'])) 
    if($_GET['variable']==GOOD VALUE I DECIDED)
      DO STUFF
    else
      KILL PAGE
```

If there are 4-5 good values I used switch etc...

I do realize the use of mysql_real_escape_string and stripslashes etc.. But is this method the best? Since I allow only known values?

Comment: What kinds of attack you want to prevent? Sql-Inj, XSS, XSRF, etc?

Comment: The GET which are sent are all to show data from the database. And there is only one POST where the field will be a URL. But almost all variables will be used to filter database fields and queries.

Comment: In fact - whitelist isn't good idea. Better will be filtering vars like in answer below, or use a `prepared statements`, where it'll be done automatically.

Comment: I'm more wondering why you allow vital variables to be sent via GET. Why not use POST?

Answer (score 0):

Never Ever trust all the request as it might be good or bad.

So you should secure your db from injection by various methods. As you might be using any mysqli or pdo for your db operations i can't advice you in that. But i shall recommend you to [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your request before you process.

Here are few example

Here is the example as real_escape_string for the select Request

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Here is the example for Insert Request after sanitizing the input

```
$contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content) VALUES('".$contentToSave."')");
```

Comment: Why not `prepared statements` in PDO ?

Comment: I am just giving the user a example to clean the inputs. The user has the choice to choose `mysqli` or `pdo` or even any framework

Answer (score 0):

You must sanitize all your dynamic data as an example:

for url sanitization you can use urlencode:

```
<a href="edit.php?client=<?php echo urlencode($clients['client_name']); ?>"><?php echo $client_name; ?></a>
```

for javascript you can use json_encode or for html you can use htmlspecialchars.